# Query XML Nodes Containing Periods In PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, period

I have a web based application used to query a number of different servers.  There is an XML file that contains all the other servers along with the ports used to communicate with those servers. If I query:

```
$File.servers.add.parameters
```

I can see a list of all the parameters for each server.  If I query:

```
$File.servers.add.parameters.specificParameter
```

I can get a list of almost all the parameters listed, however there is one parameter called

```
server.Query.Port
```

That I can't return, and I'm certain it's because it has periods in it.

I have tried

```
$File.servers.add.parameters['server.Query.Port']
```

Which returns nothing at all.  Anyone have a suggestion as to how to make this work?

Comment: we need example of the source file

Comment: Try $File.servers.add.parameters.”server.Query.Port” - from memory that *should* look for a property with the quoted string for its name, but I can’t test it myself to confirm right now...

Comment: $File.servers.add.parameters.”server.Query.Port” did it.  Not sure why I didn't try that sooner.  Thanks @mclayton

Answer (score 1):

$File.servers.add.parameters.”server.Query.Port” worked.